# Bootstrap & image responsivness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsiveness

I have a website that is totally responsive however there is one part that is not ans is situated below the slogan URBAN FREE SPIRIT (I am talking about the images)
I tried to had the class container, the class img-responsive but nothing seems to work ..

Here is my website, it will be easier to have a look through the inspector I think than with copy paste

http://v1954132.caqoajqezbu9.demo42.volusion.com/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.home-stage-v2 isn't responsive.

```
.home-stage-v2 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Apply media queries for it for the various widths.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .home-stage-v2 {
      width: 1000px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .home-stage-v2 {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Example above. You will also have to rework the images as they're with fixed width and also don't respond to width changes. I'd suggest reworking them into either percentages or putting them into a grid.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ for examples on grids.

Comment: thank for your answer Kris, what do you mean pply media queries  ?

Comment: @Ben2pop updated answer with media query examples and a link for bootstrap grids.